# Magento 2: How to get the manage_stock attribute?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, collection, stock

I'd like to get the **manage_stock** and **use_config_manage_stock** status in that looping that I've created to check before to apply the new status:

```
$useConfigManageStock = '0';
$manageStock = '0';

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();

$customStock = ['use_config_manage_stock' => $useConfigManageStock, 'manage_stock' => $manageStock];

foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $product->setStockData($customStock);
            $product->save();
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class **\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository**, in this sample below I added a new method as well.

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->_stockItemRepository->get($productId);
    }
```

So in your looping, you can use these new lines to manipulate the conditions that you need to do:

```
$productType = $product->getTypeId();

$stockItem = $this->getStockItem($product->getId());
$isManageStock = $stockItem->getManageStock();
```